# How to simulate a karma+jasmine test without the internet connection

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I would like to a make unit test that checks a certain behaviour with and without the Internet connection. Is there any possibility to do so with Jasmine + Karma?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code? Like what are you trying to test with and without internet connection?

Comment: Hey Ted, thank you for you reply. I am working with webrtc, I want to write some tests for the library I am using. So for example if there is no internet, the system should fail safely.